# Flutter: get project root's path

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get the project's root folder in Flutter? Basically what is the equivalent of python's `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Directory.current` to get your projects root directory. This is the directory where your pubspec.yaml is located. Checkout an example below.

```
import 'dart:io';
 
main() {
  Directory current = Directory.current;

  print(current);
  print(current.path);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure what you mean but if you want app directory you can use this package

> [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<Directory> getAppDirectory() async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory;
}
```